# Can you save a result (Given) to a variable in a Gherkin feature file, and then compare the variable with another result (Then)? (Cucumber for Java)

Tags: automated-tests, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am new to Cucumber for Java and trying to automate testing of a SpringBoot server backed by a MS SQL Server.

I have an endpoint "Get All Employees".

Writing the traditional feature file, I will have to list all the Employees in the `@Then` clause.
This is not possible with thousands of employees.

So I just want to get a row count of the Employee table in the database, and then compare with the number of objects returned from the "Get All Employees" endpoint.

Compare

`SELECT count(*) from EMPLOYEE`

with size of the list returned from

`List<Employee> getAllEmployees()`

But how does one save the rowcount in a variable in the feature file and then pass it into the `stepdefs` Java method?

I have not found any way that Gherkin allows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing a few scenario and feature files, I understood this about Cucumber and fixed the issue.

Gherkin/Cucumber is not a programming language. It is just a specification language. When keywords like `Given`, `Then` are reached by the interpreter, the matching methods in Java code are called. So they are just triggers.

These methods are part of a Java `glue` class. Data is not passed out of the Java class and into the gherkin feature file. The class is instantiated at the beginning and retained until the end. Because of this, it can store state.

So from my example in the question above, the `Then` response from a Spring endpoint call will be stored in a **`member variable`** in the `glue` class. The next `Then` invocation to verify the result will call the corresponding `glue` method which will access the data in the member variable to perform the comparison.

So Gherkin cannot do this, but Java at a lower level in the `glue` class, can.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a package for example named dataRun (with the corresponding classes in the package) and save there the details during the test via setters.

During the execution of the step "And I get the count of employees from the data base" you set this count via the corresponding setter, during the step "And I get all employees" you set the number via the dedicated setter. 
Then during the step "And I verify the number of employees is the same as the one in the data base" you get the two numbers via the getters and compare them.

Btw it's possible to compare the names of the employees (not just the count) if you put them into list and compare the lists.

Comment: Does Cucumber allow getters?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's the way to share data between the steps.